# Foreground Dispatcher lag

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am writing an application which uses a foreground dispatcher in order to read and write data from an NFC tag.
When I approach the tag to the phone (I can hear the system notify), my applications receives the intent after about five seconds. How can I reduce this delay?
I tried the code on a Nexus 5/Android 5.0 and a Samsung Galaxy Ace 4/Android 4.4.2. Same result.
Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

PendingIntent nfcIntent;
IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray;
String[][] techListsArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //....
    nfcIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter inf_ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter inf_tech = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    inf_ndef.addDataType("text/plain");
    intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] { inf_ndef, inf_tech };
    techListsArray = new String[][] { NFCHandler.getTechs(), NFCHandler.getAllTechs() };
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Hey!", "Intent");
    //Do something...
}

//this method is called on button press
public void startDispatcher() {
    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).enableForegroundDispatch(this,
            nfcIntent, intentFiltersArray, techListsArray);
}
}
```

Comment: If I was to set about doing NFC I would use a broadcast receiver.  I actually have a NFC phone but haven't experimented (no tags, no budget)

Comment: Ooook! You're right. Well, I was using Foreground Dispatcher because it's smarter - I can turn on and off as I want, I don't want my app starts receiving NFC intent from don't-know-where, Anyway, I saw broadcsat receiver it's way faster. Thanks! Write it as answer if you want.

Comment: Uh well, seems like it's not possible to register a broadcast receiver on a NFC action...I am obliged to declare an intent filter for the activity in the manifest...

Comment: Maybe someone will still chime in with answer?

Comment: I resolved this way: move all NFC operations in a separate Activity, declare an intent filter on it and disable (android:enable = false) in Manifest. Then, programmatically enable/disable activity as I need. Hope someone will come bringing us a better solution.